# Yii2 make default users dynamically

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

There's a way (in models/User.php) to replace default Yii users (such as admin, demo, etc...) with username and password of my custom table?

```
    private static $users = [
      '100' => [
        'id' => '100',
        'username' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'admin',
        'authKey' => 'test100key',
        'accessToken' => '100-token',
      ],
      '101' => [
        'id' => '101',
        'username' => 'demo',
        'password' => 'demo',
        'authKey' => 'test101key',
        'accessToken' => '101-token',
      ],
    ];
```

Comment: What do you mean? You are free to change this table with whatever you want...

Comment: in findByUsername function i've override default code with this: $user = Utente::find()->where(['username' => $username])->one();  but when i'm trying to login, I get this error: Calling unknown method: app\models\Utente::validatePassword()

Comment: If you are looking for DB users implementation you can copy and modify the User model from advanced template.

Answer (score 0):

you should be implement your users class from  `\yii\web\IdentityInterface` and implement  these functions

```
    public static function findIdentity($id) {

        $model = self::findOne(['users_id' => $id]);

        return ($model ? new static($model) : NULL);
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
        return null;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->users_id;
    }

    public function getAuthKey() {
        return FALSE;
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey) {

    }
public static function findByid($id) {

    return self::findOne(['users_id' => $id]);
}

public function validatePassword($password) {
    return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->uusers_password);
}

public function setPassword($password) {
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}
```

and change login form like this to get users from database

```
public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    protected function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $this->_user = Users::findByid($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for suggest, seems to work partially because after login i'm getting this error:

Argument 1 passed to yii\web\User::login() must implement interface yii\web\IdentityInterface, instance of app\models\Utente given, called in C:\Program Files (x86)\myproject\models\LoginForm.php on line 73 and defined

Problem seems to be inside: return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);

Comment: do you implement your class in this way : `class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface{
    ...
}
`???

Comment: Yes, i've edit models/User.php and implement Class in way that you have suggest.